# Lookup on Lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list: `"DocumentTypes"`

I have another list `"DocumentList"` for details on a specific document
(Ex: `Document_ID, Document_Name, Submitted_Date, Type_of_Document`)

I have a document library `"DocumentLibrary"` to which the document will be uploaded. The meta data of this document(Document Properties) will be auto filled by the details entered in the list, `'DocumentList'`. This can be done if the fields in the DocumentLibrary are all lookups on the corresponding fields of the DocumentList.

`Document_ID`, `Document_Name`, `Submitted_Date` are retrieved without a problem(involving a bit of JavaScript) but the Type_of_Document field doesn't retrieve the data from the corresponding lookup field.

(All other fields are "single line of text"s. The `type_of_document` field is a lookup)

How can I handle this? How can i perform a lookup upon a lookup field? This is not filtering a lookup field!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the data from a column from list B to appear in List C where the data originally comes from List A.

Using a workflow get the ID from the look up column and reference the source directly instead of trying to pass the data along or using a workflow copy the data into a new column and look up that column.

Conversely using a workflow you can just use the Update/Create methods to pass the information into the new list/library therefore avoiding having so many lookups which appear to me to be a waste

(If the data is coming straight from list A why do you need to get it from list B?)

Comment: Because the data in list A is static! The lookup field of B is what the user selects. And this selected value should be transferred to list C. Not all the values...

Comment: Your best bet is just to copy the information to a new column via workflow on create/update new item. Item 1 in list B is changed and will then automatically update the value in column A. List C look up will then display the new value from list B. No need for any fiddling around trying to do a look up on a look up when you can very easily create  a new column that is auto updated via WF.